# How do I pass an argument to array.map short cut?

Tags: ruby

Given the following array `a`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How do I do:

```
a.map { |num| num + 1 }
```

using the short notation:

```
a.map(&:+ 1)
```

or:

```
a.map(&:+ 2)
```

where 1 and 2 are the arguments?

Comment: Cheating: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(&:next) # => [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: You might be interested in Ruby's [Enumerators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't do it like this. The `&` operator is for turning symbols into procs.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
puts a.map(&:to_s) # prints array of strings
puts a.map(&:to_s2) # error, no such method `to_s2`.
```

`&` is a shorthand for [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

```
def to_proc
  proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
end
```

It creates and returns new proc. As you see, you can't pass any parameters to this method. You can only call the generated proc.

Comment: you are right: since array.map(&:some_method) is short hand for: class Symbol
    def to_proc
      proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
    end
end.  how do you pass in the *args?

Comment: @not_nil: you don't. Use normal block/proc.

Comment: @not_nil: Ruby doesn't support point-free style for anything that goes beyond `Symbol#to_proc`, because it lacks function composition and currying. Are you coming from a functional background?

Comment: @sergio, thanks for the quick reply.  This was more of a academic question than a real life problem.

Comment: This is not right.  & is not just for turning Symbols into Procs.  It works, as far as I know, with anything that implements a `to_proc` method.  You can define `to_proc` on `Array` to do what you want.  See Boris Stitnicky's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: @SeanMackesey To be more accurate, `&` does not turn a symbol or anything with `to_proc` to a proc. It turns a proc to a block. Applying `to_proc` is due to implicit class casting.

Answer (score 43):

In this case you can do

```
a.map(&1.method(:+))
```

But only because 1 + x is usually the same as x + 1.

[Here is a discussion of this practice in a performance context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976629/is-the-methodmethod-name-idiom-bad-for-perfomance-in-ruby)

Answer (score 27):

You cannot do it with `map`. But look at [Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets)' [Enumerable#map_send](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#map_send-instance_method):

```
require 'facets'
[1, 2, 3].map_send(:+, 1)
#=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Writing your own implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
module Enumerable
  def map_send(*args)
    map { |obj| obj.send(*args) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that you can use [Ampex](https://github.com/rapportive-oss/ampex) library, but I don't know if it is still maintained.