# Is it possible to use &: (ampersand colon) notation with a parameter or with chaining in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I want to do something like:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s(2))
```

Also, how can one do something similar to:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s(2).rjust(8, '0'))
```

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932678/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-ruby-array-map-short-cut

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:to_s` is a symbol,not a method. So you can't pass any argument to it like `:to_s(2)`. If you do so,you will get error.That's how your code wouldn't work.So `[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s(2))` is not possible,where as `[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s)` possible.`&:to_s` means you are calling `#to_proc` method on the symbol. Now in your case `&:to_s(2)` means `:to_s(2).to_proc`. Error will be happened before the call to the method `#to_proc`.

```
:to_s.to_proc # => #<Proc:0x20e4178>
:to_s(2).to_proc # if you try and the error as below

syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end
p :to_s(2).to_proc
       ^
```

Now try your one and compare the error with above explanation :

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s(2))

syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s(2))
                     ^
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need the parameters to be dynamic you could do something like this:

```
to_s2 = Proc.new {|a| a.to_s(2)}
[1, 2, 3].map &to_s2
```

And for your second example it would be:

```
to_sr = Proc.new {|a| a.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0')}
[1, 2, 3].map &to_sr
```