# Shorter way to pass every element of an array to a function

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, you can apply a map function to every element of an array:

```
@files.map { |f| f.read) }
```

For which there is the syntactic sugar:

```
@files.map(&:read)
```

Is there any equivalent for

```
@files.map { |f| read(f) }
```

That is terser, similar to the above?

Comment: It is not syntax sugar. It is just how `Symbol#to_proc` works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this

```
@files.map(&method(:read))
```

But be aware though [about performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976629/is-the-methodmethod-name-idiom-bad-for-perfomance-in-ruby).

Comment: To me, it isn't shorter at all. Just more complicated and less performant :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why would it be more complicated ?

Comment: It uses more chars, for one thing :)

Comment: I agree it's more complicated, but I'm accepting since it's the logical equivalent of the first idiom.