# How to pass a function instead of a block

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shorter way to pass every element of an array to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834846/shorter-way-to-pass-every-element-of-an-array-to-a-function)

I know this will work:

```
def inc(a)
  a+1
end
[1,2,3].map{|a| inc a}
```

but in Python, I just need to write:

```
map(inc, [1,2,3])
```

or

```
[inc(x) for x in [1,2,3])
```

I was wondering whether I can skip the steps of making a block in Ruby, and did this:

```
[1,2,3].map inc
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
# from (irb):19:in `inc'
```

Does anyone have ideas about how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834846/shorter-way-to-pass-every-element-of-an-array-to-a-function/13834860#13834860

Answer (score 108, accepted):

According to "[Passing Methods like Blocks in Ruby](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119051035/http://alan.dipert.org/post/339368222/passing-methods-like-blocks-in-ruby)", you can pass a method as a block like so:

```
p [1,2,3].map(&method(:inc))
```

Don't know if that's much better than rolling your own block, honestly.

If your method is defined on the class of the objects you're using, you could do this:

```
# Adding inc to the Integer class in order to relate to the original post.
class Integer
  def inc
    self + 1
  end
end

p [1,2,3].map(&:inc)
```

In that case, Ruby will interpret the symbol as an instance method name and attempt to call the method on that object.

---

The reason you can pass a function name as a first-class object in Python, but not in Ruby, is because Ruby allows you to call a method with zero arguments without parentheses. Python's grammar, since it requires the parentheses, prevents any possible ambiguity between passing in a function name and calling a function with no arguments.

Comment: I think another reason we cannot write `map(:inc)` directly is Ruby is a purer OO language.

Comment: Ack, forgot the `&` token, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: `Ruby will interpret the symbol as an instance method name and attempt to call the method on that object.` => Your mentioning of instance method is not correct, or is at least not clear enough. `&` converts what it is attached to into a block if it is a Proc. If it is not Proc, then it applies `to_proc`, in this case `Symbol#to_proc`.

Comment: @sawa: Very true. I couldn't think of a way to explain that concisely without sacrificing clarity; if you have a good reference, please feel free to edit my answer reflecting that.

Comment: Please fix the link

Comment: Replaced original link with link to Internet Archive.

Answer (score 13):

Does not answer your question but if you really just want to increment all your variables, you have [`Integer#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-next)

```
4.next
#=> 5

[1,2,3].map(&:next)
#=> [2, 3, 4]
```