# Modular Sinatra App: Can I Replace Blocks with Methods?

Tags: ruby, module, sinatra, modular

Have you had success refactoring your Sinatra Apps in this way?:

#### before

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class UserApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    content_type :json
    User.all.to_json
  end

  get '/:id' do |id|
    content_type :json
    User.find(id).to_json
  end

  # etc, etc.  (there are many routes)
end
```

#### after?

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'user_routes'

class UserApp < Sinatra::Base
  register UserRoutes
end

# ----- a separate file -----
module UserRoutes
  def list
    content_type :json
    User.all.to_json
  end

  def find(id)
    content_type :json
    User.find(id).to_json
  end

  def self.registered(app)
    app.get '/', &UserRoutes.list # <-- this is the piece I cannot figure out
    app.get '/:id', &UserRoutes.find # <-- this is the piece I cannot figure out

    # etc, etc.  (there are many routes)
  end
end
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to pass the UserModule's methods to `app.get` in such a way that those methods are called with the same scope as simply passing a block (e.g., how can those methods have access to `content_type` and other Sinatra features).

---

`ruby 2.0.0`

*this is a very simplified version of the problem*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to be able to call module methods with `Module.method` idiom you should declare them module-wide:

```
module UserRoutes
  #   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  def self.list
    content_type :json
    User.all.to_json
  end
  ...
end
```

Now you could:

```
app.get '/', &proc{ |_, *args| UserRoutes.send(:list, *args) }
```

Please be aware, that results in [performance penalties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976629/is-the-methodmethod-name-idiom-bad-for-perfomance-in-ruby).

[Further reading](http://www.potstuck.com/2011/08/06/ruby-symbols-instead-of-blocks/).

Comment: yikes... thanks a lot for the response @mudasobwa. This seems less than ideal and it's not the end of the world if I can't refactor that code.  Thanks again